# Как обновить просроченный токен авторизации?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

Имеется приложение, состоящее из:

- SPA на AngularJS
- WebApi бекенд
- AAD авторизация

Проблема в том, что если пользователь пару часов не обновляет страницу, токен становится просроченным и бекенд больше ничего не отдает, пока не обновишь страницу. Как можно решить такую проблему?

P.S. Попробовал adal.js, приложение начало дико тормозить и работать нестабильно. Запросы к бекенду идут гораздо дольше + не всегда обратно приходит результат.

Comment: AAD выдает вам refresh token (через который вы потом получаете access token) - этот refresh token можно достаточно долго хранить, и получать через него новые access token-ы

Comment: @PashaPash объясните, пожалуйста, как человеку, который в этом понимает меньше Вас